# fasd -e emacs not working correctly (snap installation)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, emacs, snap

fasd is working fine when I use commands such as `z` (equivalent to `fasd_cd -d`).

However when I try to do something like `fasd -e emacs .bashrc` I get a funny error message:

`/snap/fasd/2/usr/local/bin/fasd: 607: /snap/fasd/2/usr/local/bin/fasd: emacs: not found`

I'm running Pop OS (derivative of Ubuntu) and Doom emacs

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Same problem on the same OS.